# binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String!' and '[String]' in Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: string, swift

I have developed the following code and it's working fine:

```
if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
    //the code...
}
```

Now, I would like for `metadataObj.type` to be equal to an array of string like the following:

```
let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
                    AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
]

if metadataObj.type == barcodeTypes {
    //The code...
}
```

I get the following error when I use the new code:

> binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String!' and '[String]'

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: you are comparing a string to an array

Comment: I am pretty new to coding and i picked up a complicated topic at the moment. Could you please tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: let me know if that answer corresponds to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare string and array of strings, but you can use `contains`:

```
 if barcodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to check if any strings in your `barCodeTypes` array match `metadataObj.type`. You want a for in loop.

```
for barCode in barCodeTypes {
    if metadataObj.type == barCode {
       //the code...
    }
}
```

This iterates over every item in `barCodeTypes` and checks if they are equal.